# Remove any spaces when using javascript to print

Tags: jquery, printing

I would like to use javascript to print out a page but margins or paddings keep getting appended to my item to be printed out. I am using [jquery printElement](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/)!. I want my element being printed to cover the whole page. I just can't get what is wrong. Thanks for any help

on the head of the page i have

```
    @media print {
        * { margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; }
        html, body {
            /*changing width to 100% causes huge overflow and wrap*/
            height:100%;   overflow: hidden;  background: #FFF; margin: 0  !important;
        }

    }


</style>
```

but I still get this. [image: these spaces] I would like to have this printed out instead. [image]

Comment: Can you add a screen shot to show what you need to do ? and what you actually get ? like this we can get a better idea

Comment: @AbuRomaïssae I have modified to explain my difficulties thanks for the quick replay.

Comment: You want no margins at all?

Comment: @TomWalters that is correct. Everything else is ok though the margins get printed out so the picture is not covering the whole page.

Comment: can you prepare a live sample of what you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution. When using firefox, in the address bar type about:config then search for margin and set everything to 0.